# jQuery count that includes all chars including ENTER, etc?

Tags: jquery

I know that usually you want to strip these out, but I need the true char count and I can't find out how to get it...

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `length` property on any string to get its character count.  E.g.

```
'this is an example string'.length // == 26
```

or, for jQuery:

```
$('#my_textarea').html().length
```

---

N.B. use `html()` not `text()` to avoid having jQuery do things like removing line-breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Keith, I wrote a quick tutorial about this some weeks ago which will likely have the snippet you need. The demo is at [this page](http://mattswensen.com/demos/jquery-char-count.html) and the tutorial is [here](http://mattswensen.com/tutorials/jquery-char-count/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Link rot strikes again

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `.length`? That counts line breaks as characters (I assume you meant a line break by 'ENTER'?)

Comment: I'm calling .text().length and it's stripping them out. According to what I've read, .text() removes all formatting chars.

Comment: @Keith - don't use `$.text()` then! From the manual: "Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space." Because of this it wouldn't be a reliable option anyway!

Comment: Telling me it doesn't work isn't very useful... I knew that already. I was hoping for an alternative that DOES work.

Comment: @Keith - how about you post some code then? Not all of it, just the relevant snippet. What are you trying to count the characters of? Document? Input? Paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

**[This plugin](http://roy-jin.appspot.com/jsp/textareaCounter.jsp) seems to do the job.**

*It counts words too.*